# Xamarin forms учебник пользователя

Tags: xamarin.forms

Как создать учебник для пользователя в Xamarin.Forms? Я нашел библиотеку showcaseview для Xamarin.Android, но я не могу найти подходящей библиотеки для Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Что вы подрузамеваете под учебником. Однако про showcaseview. Посмотреть можно здесь  https://github.com/AmitManchanda/ShowCaseView. Как раз для XF. В описание есть ссылки на отдельные библиотек для Xamarin Android and iOS.

Comment: Спасибо, под учебником подразумевал гид (инструкцию) по приложению при первом открытии.